# cannot compile any application in Qt5 on Windows7

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I have installed Qt Creator 4.0.1 (based on Qt 5.6.1) on Windows 7 (64 bit), it finds two kits (Desktop Qt 5.6.1 MCVS2013 64bit2 and Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MCVS2013 64bit), both have two debuggers to choose (MinGW or Debugging tools for windows). So everything seems to be OK, but whenever I press Run for any simple application from examples, the Build indicator goes red, and then disappears, and the exe-file is not created, but IDE does not give any explanation to the reason why.

I'm new to Qt and really want to find out what I am doing wrong and get started with it. The error output is as follows:

```
Cannot find file: D:\рабочее\БГУИР\qt\first\myfirst\myfirst.pro.
12:30:54: The process "C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin\qmake.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project myfirst (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2013 64bit)
When executing step "qmake"
```

Maybe the Cyrillic charset causes the problem?

Comment: it's the [charset](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) that caused the problem, not the font

Comment: sorry, My English isn't perfect yet) yes, that's surely the charset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be an output of some kind somewhere. If not under the debug  tab "issues", then perhaps "Compile output".

I know that on Linux if you are running a QT example, you have to make sure you have made a copy of the code instead of running it in place. Otherwise, Qt will try to create a build folder under /opt and fail due to permission. You could also specify such a build folder when you configure the project. I am not sure whether on Windows it is going to be an issue, but it's a good place to check.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I have found it, in Application output, it says Executable D:\рабочее\БГУИР\qt\first\build-myfirst-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\debug\myfirst.exe does not exist.

Comment: in Compile output it says:

Comment: 12:30:54: Running steps for project myfirst...
12:30:54: Starting: "C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin\qmake.exe" D:\рабочее\БГУИР\qt\first\myfirst\myfirst.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2013 "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
Cannot find file: D:\рабочее\БГУИР\qt\first\myfirst\myfirst.pro.
12:30:54: The process "C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin\qmake.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project myfirst (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2013 64bit)
When executing step "qmake"
12:30:54: Elapsed time: 00:00.

Comment: @alm Please add the error outputs [to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39994696/edit) and format them properly.

Comment: @Melebius , yes, sorry, I,ve done it now. Maybe the cyrillic font in the path causes th problem, i'll check it.

Comment: oh ye, this IS the case, confound Cyrillic fonts, they cause problems half of the times.... thanks a million to those who supported me, your help let me go on.

Comment: glad you found it. I had similar problem before with Chinese characters in the path.